# Privacy concerns with windows 10 Pro

Tags: security, windows-10, privacy

I don't need any of the Windows 10 enterprise features but enterprise is the only one that (legitimately) allows me to turn off the CEIP (Customer Experience Improvement Program); this is the component that will send MS a crash dump that might potentially contain some of my customers data. Although MS take the privacy of this data quite seriously I can't honestly tell my customers that none of their data has leaked somewhere over which I have no control.

Do any organisations that handle PII (Personally Identifiable Information) data deploy Windows 10 Pro and if so how do they mitigate this threat?

Comment: This may be in the realm of "not what I'm looking for" but I ran across a freeware app recently that gathers all of these settings together in one place and lets you load and save and revert to specific settings. It's called ShutUp10 and I have been using it for all of a couple of days but it seems to do as advertised. https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10

Answer (score 1):

A moment with Google I found a HIPAA research company worked with Microsoft to release a [whitepaper](https://www.hipaaone.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/HIPAA-Compliance-Microsoft-Windows-10.pdf) about Win10, they seem to be pushing towards Enterprise. The whitepaper has only one mention of Win10 Pro/Home & it how it doesn't offer the ability to turn off telemetry. Basically if you want complete control (as it sounds you do) your organization will need to understand that Microsoft requires the Enterprise version to get it sadly. This question may be better suited for Security stack exchange. I've included other helpful links below:

- https://www.hipaaone.com/whitepaper-windows-10-hipaa-compliant
- https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/industry/health/hipaa-compliance-with-microsoft-windows-10-enterprise
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/configure-windows-diagnostic-data-in-your-organization
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/data-that-the-telemetry-agent-collects-in-office